# Rails + Puma + Transfer-Encoding: chunked response - supported or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, transfer-encoding

**Configuration**

- Rails:  4.2.7.1
- Puma:  3.8.2

--

```
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
```

I've been unable to make this work and unable to find a definitive answer:  in the above configuration, I want to stream large amounts of data to the client (in the response) - is this supported?

- If so, what is my responsibility?

  - Should my controller be emitting hexadecimal chunk sizes, `\r\n`, `0` etc?
- It feels like I want but can't find a simple response API like:

  - `write`, `write`, `write`, `flush`
  - `write`, `write`, `write`, `flush`
  - `close`
- I've read 100 posts about Rack, monkey patching and other insanity
- I've read about Puma and/or Rack mangling the encoding, possibly gzip/deflating in the wrong order
- This seems like a simple feature that should be readily available but I am stumped
- I have created numerous tests, e.g. `self.response_body = Enumerator.new` and `response.stream.write`, etc. -- all with similar results (via `curl`) - `Malformed encoding found in chunked-encoding` or `transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

Can anyone show me the light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ActionController::Live](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) API offers exactly what you describe: `response.stream.write` and `response.stream.close`. (`write` flushes a chunk automatically; you'll need to do your own buffering if that doesn't work for you.)

As long as you `include ActionController::Live` (and note that affects the behaviour of the entire controller, not just one action), you should then be able to write a streaming response with no further effort: you need not, and should not, set any headers etc related to chunking.

Additional reference: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

Comment: Not exactly - the API you cite sets the `Content-Type: text/event-stream` header which not all browsers support.  (AFAIK)  Also, I don't t think this is a scalable solution due to threading implementation.

Comment: The _example_ uses that content type; you can set yours to whatever you like.

Comment: I think you're confused - the `Transfer-Encoding` not the `Content-Type` header is what's relevant to this discussion.  Presumably you know how `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` works and how the client is to process it.  The `Content-Type: text/event-stream` produces server side events and not all clients (browsers) support this.  All browsers, on the other hand, support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Comment: def show
    response.headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"
    100.times {
      response.stream.write "hello world\n"
    }
  ensure
    response.stream.close
end

Result:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<snip>
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
</snip>
Connection: close
Server: thin

curl: (56) Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
@matthewd

Comment: _you need not, **and should not**, set any headers etc related to chunking_. (Also, thin isn't puma.)

Comment: OK - I think we're going around in circles then as my original question still stands - how to employ `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.  `Content-Type: text/event-stream` (i.e., server sent events) although interesting is not what I'm asking about.  I do appreciate your comments nonetheless. @matthewd

Comment: Follow the example in the ActionController::Live doc. Set the content type to whatever you like, but change nothing else. The chunking will be managed by Puma. By trying to set the header yourself you are disabling the built-in functionality.

Comment: you are 100% correct.  I did not understand what was happening in my development environment - I did not realize that Thin was running instead of Puma.  In fact, I didn't even know "Thin" was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Important addendum to @matthewd 's wonderful answer:

The Rack specification supports a streaming response through [the use of the `each` method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#label-The+Body) on the response object or through [the use of `hijack`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#label-Hijacking).

@matthewd is right when stating that:

> The ActionController::Live API offers exactly what you describe...

However, the implementation either hijacks the socket or uses the Rack specification's "hack" with the `each` method.

The best case scenario is that the implementation hijacks the socket and runs it on a new thread (which is what it should normally do, AFAIK).

However, this could result in quite a lot of threads and **could become performance heavy** - threads cost in memory space for stack data (1Mb-2Mb per thread / client) and context switches become more expensive as more threads are created.

In the worst case scenario, **a slow `each` loop will block a server's thread**, crippling the server and eventually resulting in a DoS situation.

The correct answer should be NOT to stream data over a single HTTP request - use a **native*** WebSockets, SSE or AJAX solution instead.

Another semi-correct method would save all the data to a temporary file and sending the file using a server that supports static file streaming outside the Ruby layer (such as [iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine)) or a proxy (such as nginx).

* Native: A native WebSocket / SSE solution follows [this Rack proposal](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1272) and allows the server to handle the network layer rather than running another thread / IO reactor. See [this blog post](https://bowild.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/rubys-rack-push-decoupling-the-real-time-web-application-from-the-web/) for more details.